Rotate Curve Profile independent of Curve Vector
Is there a simple way to get the curve profile to stay rotated in one direction, independent of the curve's vector? Eg. Always flat, Z+1.00.
Align Euler to vector I feel like should work, but doesn't.
Thanks


You're saying that what your aiming for is that top image there? Not what you currently have? I'm not 100% clear on your intended outcome.

I think the simplest way is to loft manually:


